# How to undo nuget package installation in TFS without undoing project added files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget-package

I have installed a nuget package to my project that is in TFS but now i want to undo this operation but undoing the operation will undo the edition in the project file but if i do this then other files that i have been added in the project will not be added.
How can i undo this without loosing the other files association to the project?

Answer (score 1):

Open the project file in a text editor, remove the references you do not require. 
Edit the packages file and remove the line for the package you want to remove

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who come across this answer and try it (like I did). It doesn't work (anymore, maybe it did on a VS 2013 or older?). If you do this in e.g. VS2019 a XAML design window will show *Some Assembly References are missing* instead. No further useful info of course, VS never does give that.

In VS2019, just right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select Manage NuGet Packages. Check the package you want to delete (project + package name) and click the delete button. This works without these errors.